# Translation of a seal from a modern Chinese print (Characters identified: 榮寶齋製)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image]could anyone help me with the reading of this seal, it is from a Chinese print[image]

Comment: Looks like 榮全齊 or 齊榮全 + 制. I can’t find anyone with those names.

Comment: Thank you, I'm thinking it's a collectors seal on the artwork. The other two seals are the artists.

Comment: In that case, the intention is probably to write 榮寶齋製 (Made at [Róng Bǎo Zhāi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rong_Bao_Zhai)). The seal uses a weird mixture of not-really-correct ancient character substitutions, as well as Simplified Chinese.

Comment: @dROOOze - I'm curious how you knew the part that looks like three sewing needles represented 齊 or 齋. Would it be a correct ancient character substitution for 齊, but not for 齋?

Comment: @aguijonazo Spot on! It's the [original character of  「齊」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=3758), which depicts 3 plants arranged in a neat and tidy arrangement, indicating the meanings *uniform, equal*. This is preserved in the top half of what is now 「齊」. The lines underneath are decorative strokes that don't contribute to the word (a common character complexification process). Using this character for 「齋」 is not strictly correct from a language perspective, but I guess if you take artistic liberty you can say that someone is trying to use it as a phonetic loan for 「齋」.

Comment: ... But, the thing is, that original shape is found on on oracle bone and bronze inscriptions, so if you want to write in that style, you should use other characters in that style for the rest of the seal as well. It's rather jarring to see 「宝」 instead of [「寳」 , because the latter is contemporary](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=5056) with that old shape of 「齊」, while the former was exceedingly rare or nonexistent in those times, only arising much later.

Comment: I just added another seal, the top left is the more accurate representation of 齋?

Comment: both seals i have posted are from different pieces of art but by the same artist

Comment: Ok the new seal you added definitely says 榮寶齋製. I’ll write an answer.